# Dynamic Open Graph meta tags in a static GatsbyJS site hosted on S3

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, facebook-opengraph, server-side-rendering, share-open-graph

The app can take users's info and signup his account. Then the user can post his referral link, like `www.site.com/username`, to social media and a unique image (having user's name and username), generated for each user on sign up, should be displayed as Open Graph image on social platforms.

I have tried using [Gatsby Helmet Plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/) but apparently, the meta tags added by helmet are not added to the index file that can be **scraped** by crawlers.

The only possible way I can see for now is migrating my app to NextJS and that's going to be quite some work. Is there is any way I can make it work in Gatsby? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Edit: Another possible way could be to deploy this gatsby app to a server, render the app on the server, and then returning the rendered response. Basically converting it to a server-side rendered app. Is this possible or is there any good way of achieving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

[Netlify](http://netlify.com) ♥

---

So basically Netlify has it's own "Prerendering" feature. I attached my Github CI/CD with Netlify, turned that Prerendering option on, and it worked like charm.

Thanks to google and all those random articles that pointed me to Netlify. Lambda@edge is another thing that people are using for similar server side rendering where they point CloudFront directly with Lambda@Edge instead of S3. I might shift my web app to Lambda@Edge if I got that to work, but for now, Netlify won!